# LayoutManager and RecyclerView Issues When Creating RecyclerView For Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Quick note: I'm not very experienced with java or android studio, so please bare with my noobish question.

I'm working on a project that has a fragment with RAL colors. There are just a little over 280 images total. I am trying to create a recyclerView for this fragment. To prevent this question from being miles longer than it already is, I've cut out some of the colors in the ralfragment.

I want the layout of the of the colors to look like this:

```
image1  image2  image3

image4  image5  image6

...

image280 image281

(The last line only has 2 images.)
```

I've watched a few tutorials (none of them worked with rv in fragments) and tried to implement what they did into my project, but I get the following error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{ab3c28d VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0800a2 app:id/recyclerView}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.westcoastpowdercoating.WestCoastPowderCoating.MainActivity@3b25cc8b
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:4304)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at com.westcoastpowdercoating.WestCoastPowderCoating.ralfragment.onCreateView(ralfragment.java:23)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Guessing from this error, The layoutmanager or the recyclerviewer is not connecting. I'm not sure where I went wrong. Would I have to make something in my MainActivity.java? In the tutorial I watched, they made most of what I have in my ralfragment.java in their MainActivity.java, but I thought I would have to move it to my ralfragment.java because that is the fragment I need the recycvlerView for.

This is my ralfragment.java:

```
    public class ralfragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ral, container, false);

    ArrayList<ralcolor> ralcolors= new ArrayList<>();
    ralcolors.add(new ralcolor(R.drawable.ral1000, R.drawable.ral1001, R.drawable.ral1002));
    ralcolors.add(new ralcolor(R.drawable.ral1003, R.drawable.ral1004, R.drawable.ral1005));
    ralcolors.add(new ralcolor(R.drawable.ral1006, R.drawable.ral1007, R.drawable.ral1011));

    ralcolors.add(new ralcolor(R.drawable.ral1012, R.drawable.ral1013, R.drawable.ral1014));
    ralcolors.add(new ralcolor(R.drawable.ral1015, R.drawable.ral1016, R.drawable.ral1017));
    ralcolors.add(new ralcolor(R.drawable.ral1018, R.drawable.ral1019, R.drawable.ral1020));


    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mAdapter =  new Adapter(ralcolors);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.viewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ralcolor> mralcolors;

public static class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView mImageView1;
    public ImageView mImageView2;
    public ImageView mImageView3;

    public viewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1000);
        mImageView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1001);
        mImageView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1002);
    }
}

public Adapter(ArrayList<ralcolor> ralcolors) {
    mralcolors  = ralcolors;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_ral, viewGroup, false);
    viewHolder vh = new viewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
ralcolor currentcolor = mralcolors.get(i);

    viewHolder.mImageView1.setImageResource(currentcolor.getmImageResource1());
    viewHolder.mImageView2.setImageResource(currentcolor.getmImageResource2());
    viewHolder.mImageView3.setImageResource(currentcolor.getmImageResource3());
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mralcolors.size();
}
}
```

My RAL xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1000"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1001"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1002"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My ral color retriever java:

```
    package com.westcoastpowdercoating.WestCoastPowderCoating;

public class ralcolor {
private int mImageResource1;
private int mImageResource2;
private int mImageResource3;

public ralcolor(int imageResource1, int imageResource2, int 
imageResource3) {
    mImageResource1 = imageResource1;
    mImageResource2 = imageResource2;
    mImageResource3 = imageResource3;
}

public int getmImageResource1() {
    return mImageResource1;
}

public int getmImageResource2() {
    return mImageResource2;
}

public int getmImageResource3() {
    return mImageResource3;
}

}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Did you initialize recyclerview Library to your gradle ? Can you check your gradle whether you have recyclerview library or not ? Try to add this     implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1' if you dont have this library , after adding update your recyclerview imports from your MainActivity.

Comment: I have implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0' in my gradle

Comment: try my code please

Comment: Are you sure that's an error? Does it actually crash your app?

Comment: @JDevoloper why would using an older and mismatched version of the RecyclerView library change anything?

Comment: It says "this library should not use a different version (27) than compileSDK version (28)" I tried syncing it anyways and still have the same error.

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes, it crashes the app as soon as I open the RAL fragment. The other fragments work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put children inside a RecyclerView in XML. It looks like what you have there currently is what you want to be in your ViewHolder. That's not how to do it.

Make a new layout XML file and move what's wrapped in your RecyclerView into that file.

Then change the `inflate()` argument inside `onCreateViewHolder()` to use the proper layout (change `R.layout.fragment_ral`).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that they couldn't have children.

Comment: They actually can, and do. Each list item is a child. It just has to be done dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

- The reason is LayoutManager of recyclerview.
- The layoutmanager has 3 sub classes: LinearLayoutManager, GridLayoutManager and StaggeredGridLayoutManager.
- You can try LinearLayoutManager with recyclerview
- Example:`LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
  manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
  myRecycler.setLayoutManager(manager);`
- Hope you can resolve your issue. And you can refer [the link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465). Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I know. But the log show error is `RecyclerView has no LayoutManager`. So I suggest try to use LinearLayoutManager to resolve it.

Comment: So how does telling the OP to set a LayoutManager in code help? They're already doing that.